# Javascript Calculator: How can I create an operator button based on a condition?

Tags: javascript, button, calculator

This is my first attempt at using Javascript, so this is likely a simple problem that I just don't have experience with.

I'm trying to create a calculator operator button based on the condition that the first letter in a username is between A-M in the alphabet. I've tested this with a sample username, and the condition I created worked successfully. However, I'm currently getting a "TypeError: Cannot set property 'className' of undefined" in this statement:

```
if (let_am.includes(username.split("")[0])){
          var add = document.createElement("button");
          add.className = "operator";
          add.dataAction = "add";
          add.innerHTML = "+";
          var body = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
          body.appendChild(add);
```

I've defined the var "add" right before giving it a className, so I'm not sure what is undefined.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the error is on that line of your code? NB: unrelated, but there is no need to call `.split("")`. Just remove that part.

Comment: i dont think the error is what you said.

Answer (score 0):

From your code snippet, there are a few things that need correction.
First, instead of using `var` you can use the new ES6 variable declaration keywords which are `let` and `const`, you could google the differences between these three keywords and why you should use the new keywords.

To answer your question, the error thrown is `TypeError: cannot set property className of undefined`. This means that you are trying to use `add` in an inappropriate way.

You could try doing this `add.className += 'operator'` or `add.classList.add('operator')`.